# Extracting values from dataframe with multiple column names for the rows

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, osmnx

I am working on a CVRP problem, for which I've created a GeoDataFrame with nodes that have NodeIDs and edges spanning from one NodeID to another.

I have node and edge data extracted from OSMnx. The GeoDataFrame I get for the [edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i17bb.png) has three indices for a single row name. As can be seen in the picture, these are: u, v and key.

I want to be able to select an edge from this GeoDataFrame by entering a unique value for u and v (nodeIDs) so it returns the edge length. But I have no idea how to do this with three index columns per row.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Similarly, the GeoDataFrame for the [nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LigkD.png) will not let me select a row by trying `nodes.loc['46367195',0]` for example to receive the 'y' data for the node corresponding to NodeID 46367195. Or some variation.

Comment: Embed your image for easier access to everyone

Answer (score 0):

It is a MultiIndex, aka [hierarchical index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html), as stated in the OSMnx [documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs):

> gdf_nodes is indexed by osmid and gdf_edges is multi-indexed by u, v, key following normal MultiDiGraph structure

You can work with it as you would any pandas MultiIndex.